# dladdr and names of functions in anonymous namespaces

Tags: c++

I am attempting to return the name of a function given its pointer using `dladdr`, which is commonly used in various software libraries.  However, I'm finding different behavior with GCC vs. Apple Clang.  Take the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <dlfcn.h>

namespace {
    std::string function_name(void const* f)
    {
      Dl_info di;
      auto res = dladdr(f, &di);
      if (res && di.dli_sname) {
        return di.dli_sname;
      }
      return {};
    }
}
 
namespace { void foo() {} }
void bar() {}

int main() {
    std::cout << "1." << function_name((void const*)&foo) << '\n'
              << "2." << function_name((void const*)&bar) << '\n';
}
```

Compiling this with GCC 13.1 (see https://godbolt.org/z/aWdGoKveT), I get the following result:

```
1.
2._Z3barv
```

IOW, the name of the function in the anonymous namespace is not accessible.  If I compile the above with Apple Clang 14.0.3, I do have access to the name of the function in anonymous

```
1._ZN12_GLOBAL__N_13fooEv
2._Z3barv
```

Is there a way to control the GCC behavior such that I *do* get the name `foo`?

Comment: I don't see `_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_13fooEv` in clang 14.0.0 in your link. So the question is to AppleClang.

Comment: _Is there a way to control the GCC behavior such that I do get the name `foo`?_  Only by declaring it as `extern "C"`

Comment: You may not make it `extern "C"` in a namespace.

Comment: @273k Yes, I suspected as much.  OP, what lies behind this question?  Why are you trying to get the name of that function (and why is it in an anonymous namespace)?